# Создать и вывести список в Python

Tags: python, trello

У меня есть список members,который получается таким образом:

```
members = Organization.get_members(org1)
```

где `Organization` – это класс, `get_members()` его поле. Это все работает.

Теперь мне нужно вывести имена всех пользователей из списка `members` и автоматически присвоить им номер от `0` до (количество пользователей списка – 1) при чем, чтобы `0` соответствовал `members[0].full_name`; `1` - `members[1].full_name`.

Тоесть должна получится табличка:

```
Asignee: 0-Roman, 1-Serg, 2-Anton …
```

и так далее, где имена – это `members[index].full_name`, а значение `index` должно совпадать с цифрой перед  дефисом.

Comment: Ну и в чем проблема-то?

Comment: @Эникейщик в этом и проблема, чтобы 0 соответствовал член members под 0 индексом в списке members и т.д. до всех членов members. Тоесть программа должна выводить пользователей ровно столько, сколько их есть в members, при этом автоматически определяя сколько их там находится.

Comment: Судя по фрагменту кода, вы не первый день с питоном. Поэтому странно, что вы спрашиваете, как поштучно вывести элементы списка...

Comment: Не первый день, но вот ответ @Andrio Skur (использовать enumerate) решил мою проблему. Век живи - век учись, как говорится.

Comment: Да можно и не использовать.

Comment: тогда почему не написал, как это можно сделать без enumerate, я бы защитал твой ответ?

Comment: ну, во-первых, с enumerate элегантнее, а во-вторых, это же совсем азы - вывести список через ``for member in members:``...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то:

```
print(*enumerate(member.full_name for member in Organization.get_members(org1)), sep='\n')
```

Comment: это близко, но тогда получается результат (0, <Member 5965ea0f40c5feef6a2741f8>) (1, <Member 52551dedeb7f848b0500060f>), а мне нужно, чтобы было (0, Roman),(1, Serhii) тоесть напротив цифры выводился не обьект, а полное имя.

Comment: for i, item in enumerate(members):
            print(" {} - {}".format(i, members[i].full_name))

Answer (score 2):

Когда вы хотите получит список паров, можете сделать так:

```
result = [(i, member.full_name) for i, member in enumerate(members)]
```

---

Объяснение:

`enumerate(members)` добавит *порядковый номер* для всякого *объекта* списка `members`, а пара

```
 (i, member.full_name)
```

использует эти порядковые номера *прямо*, но вместо частного *объекта* (`member`) подставит его *атрибут* (`full_name`).